# How do I properly update Python on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, python, updates

If I download python from the Python website and try to install it with the installer, it installs, but I need to specify that I want the new version of Python when I run my programs from terminal. If I just type:

```
python app.py
```

It runs with the old version.

How do can I set the new version as default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found how to do it.
The installer made a python 2.6 folder in /Application
In this folder is a script called Update Shell Profile.command
I just needed to execute it and now it's working.

Comment: Yep. Python 2.6 now includes a script to make it the default on the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Two questions:

1. Where did the new Python get installed?
2. What does your $PATH look like?

A default set-up on Unix-like systems is that user-installed software gets installed in /usr/local/bin, and most *nix distros put that directory *before* system-wide directories in the default $PATH variable (which is how your shell knows where to look for programs). That way, if you install something new, the new item gets found first.

However, a default OS X $PATH looks like this:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

The problem is that by putting */usr/local/bin* so late, the system-wide Python (which is at */usr/bin* and so earlier in your $PATH) keeps getting hit.

My answer is to make my $PATH look like this on a Mac:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

To do that, create a file *.profile* in your home directory and add something like this:

```
#### Let's take care of our $PATH
# A backup of the original $PATH
# /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

# My preferred order - /usr/local goes first, damn it!
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

**Edit**: I'm following up here, rather than in comments because it's getting too long for a comment. The line in your *.profile* with `/sw/bin/init.sh` comes from the package manager [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/), which I'm assuming you use (or used at some point). The other line seems to suggest that at some point you installed MacPython and it rewrote your `$PATH` for you. I don't know MacPython, but if it's [this site](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jack/macpython/), then it hasn't been updated since 2004. It also doesn't seem to talk about any version of OS X beyond 10.3, which is not very current.

So now I'm more confused: when did you update Python? How did you update it? What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: est -r /sw/bin/init.sh && . /sw/bin/init.sh
    # Setting PATH for MacPython 2.6
    # The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave
    PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:${PATH}"
    export PATH

    This is how my .profile looks, I'm not sure what I should do since it's different from your's. [Is' there a way to format code in comments?]

Comment: @Philippe: You can format code by using backquotes, just as in posts. See the post itself for my response to the larger issue.

Comment: I finally found how to solve it. The installer made a folder in my application directory wich contains the idle, some examples and *a script* to update the command line. And for the MacPython thing, I think it got installed with xcode. Thanks for trying to help me anyway.

Comment: @Telemachus I believe MacPython refers to the .dmg installer from http://python.org/download/

Comment: @Las3rjock: Cool, that's much better than my guess! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1):

Find out where python lives:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

See if it's a symlink:

```
$ ls -Fal /usr/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root wheel  72 May 19 12:02 /usr/bin/python@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python
```

If so, link /usr/bin/python to the new python:

```
$ sudo ln -s (new python, maybe /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.x/bin/python) /usr/bin/python
```

Check if it works:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.xxx
```

Comment: He should absolutely *NOT* undo the system's default Python in this way. OS X expects it to be where it is. This would be a huge mistake.

Comment: It's a legitimate answer to the question.  I've done it before without anything blowing up.

Any other method won't result in programs with a bang path of /usr/bin/python using the new right one.

Comment: @Bill: I think it's a terrible approach. You can always script with a shebang of `#!/usr/bin/env python`, and you should not replace a system-wide perl or python if you can avoid it.

Comment: I'm with Telemachus on this. Let the standard Mac stuff remain as is. Custom installations go in /usr/local or /opt/local and adjust PATH and other environment variables as necessary.